# How can get information of a contact in address book in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

i need get image and name from a contact. I have the id but I can't obtain the information, because the method is deprecated, How can I make this in Swift??

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordID recordId = (ABRecordID)[contactId intValue];
    ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recordId);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which method is deprecated? have
ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL) instead ABAddressBookCreate

Comment: thanks! but now I get other error, when I want get the image.. var addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
        var person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook.takeRetainedValue(), ident); var imgData = (ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person.takeRetainedValue(), kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize)) var image: UIImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgData) unmanaged CFData to UIImage. Write other questions with this problem?? or can answer here?